# My data doesnot get recorded in the SQLite DB on my android app

Tags: android, android-sqlite

OK guys, before i as more, i searched the forum and many others but i didnt seem to find the adequate answer so i thought i might ask, i've created this app for organizing the day and it works somehow like this:
 - I have 2 activities, the one is to show the data (on a list view) and the other is just for insertion, i opened the second activity with the `startActivityForResult` function and then get the data back and with the `onActivityResult` function i insert it into the database.
Eclipse doesent show me any errors, nor does the LogCat but the data doesent seem to get inserted into the Db, so i inserted a try-catch method while inserting the data to log what is done, and i always get the exception that the data was not recorded. I am new into android and i dont think i do everything right. I posted all the code of the application so you have a overview of the whole process but the problem (i think) is somewhere where the data base is created, or the data is inserted, or maybe at the activities when i try to get the data from one to the other. but i dont know where so please help!

the MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.dailyplanner;

import android.R.id;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnCreateContextMenuListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {


    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    Intent weather;     
    Intent i;
    String text;
    String date;
    String time;
    ListView lv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TaskTbl (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, text VARCHAR(250), time VARCHAR(20), date VARCHAR(20));");


        Button showBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shTask);
        showBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {



            }
        });


        Button nTaskBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nTask);
        nTaskBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent nTaskScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext() new_task.class);

                startActivityForResult(nTaskScreen, 100);



            }
        });



        Button wthrBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wthrBtn);
        registerForContextMenu(wthrBtn);


        lv = (ListView) findViewById(id.list);



    }








    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
        mi.inflate(R.menu.cities, menu);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode==100)
        {
            i = getIntent();        
        String text = i.getStringExtra("text");
            String date = i.getStringExtra("date");
            String time = i.getStringExtra("time");
                try{


                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO TaskTbl (text,time,date) VALUES("+text+", "+time+", "+date+");");        

                Log.d("db","data was recorded");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("db", "data was not recorded");

            }



        }

    }
}
```

New_task.java:

```
package com.example.dailyplanner;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.UrlQuerySanitizer.ValueSanitizer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.renderscript.Sampler.Value;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class new_task extends Activity {

    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID=0;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID=1;
    public TextView timeText;
    public TextView dateText;
    public EditText taskText;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_task);


        timeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeTxt);
        dateText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateTxt);
        taskText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),     MainActivity.class);

                i.putExtra("date", dateText.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("time", timeText.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("text", taskText.getText().toString());

                setResult(100);

                finish();




            }
        });



        Button btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                finish();


            }
        });


    Button btnSetTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetTime);
        btnSetTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);

            }
            });

        Button btnSetDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetDate);
        btnSetDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

            }
        });



    }

    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new     TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    timeText.setText(hourOfDay+":"+minute);
                    };

    };


    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {

            dateText.setText(dayOfMonth+"."+monthOfYear+"."+year);

        }
    };


    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
        switch(id){

        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, 0, 0, true);

        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, 2011, 1, 28);


        }
        return null;

    }


}
```

here's the LogCat:

```
10-13 15:57:44.825: D/CLIPBOARD(9334): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
10-13 16:03:17.020: D/dalvikvm(10612): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 135K, 4% free 12839K/13255K, paused 27ms
10-13 16:03:17.020: I/dalvikvm-heap(10612): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.069MB for 379472-byte allocation
10-13 16:03:17.075: D/dalvikvm(10612): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 13209K/13639K, paused 55ms
10-13 16:03:17.115: D/AbsListView(10612): Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-13 16:03:17.305: D/CLIPBOARD(10612): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
10-13 16:03:21.740: D/dalvikvm(10612): GC_CONCURRENT freed 62K, 2% free 13626K/13895K, paused 3ms+2ms
10-13 16:03:21.790: D/dalvikvm(10612): GC_CONCURRENT freed 6K, 2% free 14073K/14343K, paused 2ms+2ms
10-13 16:03:21.825: D/AbsListView(10612): Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-13 16:03:21.875: D/dalvikvm(10612): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 80K, 2% free 14324K/14599K, paused 13ms
10-13 16:03:23.130: D/dalvikvm(10612): GC_CONCURRENT freed 175K, 3% free 14678K/15047K, paused 2ms+4ms
10-13 16:03:28.910: D/AndroidRuntime(10612): Shutting down VM
10-13 16:03:28.910: W/dalvikvm(10612): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c6f1f8)
10-13 16:03:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(10612): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 16:03:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(10612): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=100, data=null} to activity {com.example.dailyplanner/com.example.dailyplanner.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
10-13 16:03:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2994)
10-13 16:03:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3037)
10-13 16:03:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:128)
10-13 16:03:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1191)
10-13 16:03:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-13 16:03:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-13 16:03:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
10-13 16:03:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 16:03:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-13 16:03:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
10-13 16:03:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
10-13 16:03:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-13 16:03:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(10612): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
10-13 16:03:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
10-13 16:03:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:92)
10-13 16:03:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:2020)
10-13 16:03:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1960)
10-13 16:03:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at com.example.dailyplanner.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:182)
10-13 16:03:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4746)
10-13 16:03:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2990)
10-13 16:03:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always post the stack trace from logcat when asking about an exception.

However, I can see why your insert fails.  Text data and dates should be delimited with single quotes.

```
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (myTextData)
```

will fail

```
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('myTextData')
```

will work.

Use "'" + text + "'"

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO TaskTbl (text,time,date) VALUES(" + "'" + text + "', '" + time + "', '" + date + "');");
```

When building strings like this, use the syntax colour highlighting in your IDE editor to check that you have the quotes in the right place. For example, in my IDE, strings are shown in green and identifiers are black.

[EDIT]

The constraint exception means that you are trying to add a duplicate row.  If duplicates are not allowed, then you should handle this exception accordingly.  If duplicates are allowed, then use the _id column as the primary.  I think you might have tried to do this but your create statement adds a column called "id", not "_id".  If in fact you meant to use "id", then you must use a unique value for that column in the INSERT since you have specified that it is the primary key.